# Azure AAD B2C - history of profile changes

Tags: azure-active-directory, aad-b2c

I use AAD B2C as an identity provider within my application and I would need to keep history log of user profile edits - have history of changes such as user changed his name / email / password (of course not storing the password value). I am able to do it myself by including logging step inside the profile edit / password reset flows, but I wanted to ask if there is some activity log where I could find entries related to changes of user profiles out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [AAD activity logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-activity-logs-azure-monitor) in [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) for this. Certain features such as password logs are contained with their respective features. For example, [reporting for SSPR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-reporting). Please let me know if this solves your question or if you had something else in mind.

Best,
James

Comment: hi @James_Hamil-MSFT, thank you for your answer. On the first glimpse it looks like what I was searching for. Please give me some time to dig bit deeper, to confirm it meets my requirements  and I will get back here to mark your answer.

Comment: thank you audit log provides what I was looking for. However I found one issue, When I alter users login email, everything works well, however audit trail does not surface the information it was changed. Modified properties field does not display email property.